# How can I change the main toolbar color in Quasar?

Tags: quasar-framework

I'm running quasar 1.7.2, and when I go to change the color of the main toolbar in the basic example app, it won't change. If I go to MainLayout.vue I have the following code near the top of the file

```
    <q-header elevated>
      <q-toolbar color = "green-8">


        <q-btn

          flat
          dense
          round
          color = "green-8"
          icon="menu"
          aria-label="Menu"
          @click="leftDrawerOpen = !leftDrawerOpen"
        />

        <q-toolbar-title>
          Del Norte FIU 1
        </q-toolbar-title>



        <div>Serial: 6654521</div>


      </q-toolbar>
    </q-header>
```

This should turn the toolbar green according to the link below, however it does not.

https://v0-17.quasar-framework.org/components/toolbar.html

Oddly, the line modifying the color of the button to green-8 does indeed work on the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `bg-green-8` class. The opening tag should look like `<q-toolbar class="bg-green-8">` to change the color to green.

Codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/bGVLbJQ